# An error due to the use of & instead of *

Tags: c

I'm working with the MySQL C API and trying to execute a prepared statement to delete a row.

```
   -(void) deleteOne:(int) num
{
    [self initAndConnectSql];
    char copy[30] = "call delete";
    strncat(copy, _name, 15);
    strncat(copy, "(?)", 4);
    MYSQL_STMT * prepared = mysql_stmt_init(&_mysql);
    mysql_stmt_prepare(prepared, copy, strlen(copy));
    MYSQL_BIND bind[1];
    bind[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_LONG;
    bind[0].buffer = &num;
    bind[0].is_null=0;
    bind[0].length= 0;
    if (mysql_stmt_bind_param(prepared, bind))
    {
        printf("error in binding params");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (mysql_stmt_execute(prepared))
    {
        printf("Error executing prepared statement");
        exit(1);
    }
    mysql_stmt_close(prepared);
    mysql_close(&_mysql);
}
```

This code works fine. But previously when I didn't set the prepared variable as a pointer, I got a pointer being freed was not allocated set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug error. The line was `MYSQL_STMT prepared = *mysql_stmt_init(&_mysql);`.
My question is why does setting prepared as a pointer, versus passing in &prepared where it is needed, work? Shouldn't a pointer and an & be equivalent since a pointer stores the address of what it is pointing at and & returns the address, so to a function, they are the same?

Comment: What is the type that `mysql_stmt_init` returns? Do the types `MYSQL_STMT` and `MYSQL_STMT *` differ? Does answering these two questions answer your question?

Comment: You should have gotten a compiler warning for a type mismatch long before you needed to resort to running a debugger.  Did you disable warnings for some reason?

Comment: I didn't. The compiler did not throw any warnings. And the init function returns a pointer to a MYSQL_stmt structure. The thing is, the compiler actually recommended I insert an * in front of the function instead of prepared and no errors were thrown until execution reached stmt_close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manual for `mysql_stmt_close`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-stmt-close.html):

> Closes the prepared statement. mysql_stmt_close() also deallocates the
>   statement handle pointed to by stmt.

If you do:

```
MYSQL_STMT prepared = *mysql_stmt_init(&_mysql);
mysql_stmt_close(&prepared);
```

That passes a pointer to a *stack* variable into the `mysql_stmt_close` function which will then try to `free` it resulting in the error you saw. Instead, you must pass in the original pointer returned by `mysql_stmt_init` as shown in your first code snippet. `mysql_stmt_init` returns dynamic memory (obtained via `malloc` or similar function) which then needs to be freed by `mysql_stmt_close`.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. So basically, because I didn't declare prepared as a pointer variable, it is actually a local variable inside this function, and thus on the stack? And this stack variable's value is the address of the dynamic memory created  by mysql_stmt_init? Since i had assigned prepared to the return value of the init, which is a pointer.

Comment: "And this stack variable's value is the address of the dynamic memory created by mysql_stmt_init?". Not quite. The stack variable's value is a copy of the values pointed to by the return value of `mysql_stmt_init`. The original pointer/memory returned by `mysql_stmt_init` is lost after that line executes (ie, a dangling pointer resulting in memory leak).

Comment: I see. Thanks for answering. this is my first foray into C territory so I'm still trying to wrap my head around stacks/heaps and pointers.

Answer (score 0):

From the [MySQL API](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-stmt-init.html):

```
23.8.11.15 mysql_stmt_init()
----------------------------

MYSQL_STMT *mysql_stmt_init(MYSQL *mysql)

Description

Create a MYSQL_STMT handle. The handle should be freed with mysql_stmt_close(MYSQL_STMT *).
```

The `mysql_stmt_init()` function returns a *pointer* to a `MYSQL_STMT`.  The part saying that it "should be freed" implies that it is dynamically allocated from the heap.  The value returned is the memory address (pointer) of this heap memory.  To properly free it, the same memory address (pointer value) must be given to `mysql_stmt_close()`.

When you use your original `MYSQL_STMT prepared = *mysql_stmt_init(&_mysql);` version, you are *copying the value* of the `MYSQL_STMT` returned into the local variable `prepared`, which resides on the stack.  When you take the address of this to give to `mysql_stmt_close(&prepared)` you are not giving the original memory address from the heap that you were given by `mysql_stmt_init()`.